# Changing a tile's appearance on hover or press

Tags: gridview, winrt-xaml, visualstatemanager

In a GridView (Metro-style XAML app), I want one of my tiles to have a VCR-style "pause" icon on it. But when the user hovers over the button (with the mouse) or presses the button, I want the icon to change to "play". (I want to give subtle cues to reinforce the idea that it's paused now, but pressing the button will start playing.)

How can I detect whether the mouse is over the tile, and whether the tile is pressed, so I can change my tile's appearance?

Ideally I'd like to hook into the tile's VisualStateManager. But I'm still a newbie to the VisualStateManager, and when I'm editing my ItemTemplate, I don't see any visual states available. (Blend's "States" docked window is empty.)

If I make a copy of the ItemContainerTemplate and edit that, then I can get at the visual states for the tile. But that seems like *incredible* overkill. It adds reams upon reams of XAML (since it means duplicating every last bit of functionality that's supported by any tile anywhere). And it means that if Microsoft makes any changes before Windows 8 ships, I'll have to make my changes all over again.

Is there a lighter-weight way to change my tile's appearance in the "pointer over" and "pressed" states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.  Sadly if you want to change how the control behaves you need to over-ride the template.  I've done exactly what you've described to change the look and feel of the template.  It's a pain in the neck.

I read somewhere that "Xaml makes it incredibly easy to do the incredibly hard and incredibly hard to do the incredibly easy".  This pretty much sums up my experience with it.

Sorry I couldn't deliver better news.